# Linking to the C++ runtime with a Flutter app on Android

Tags: android, c++, flutter, gradle, android-ndk

I'm trying to make use of a prebuilt dynamic library in a Flutter (v2.2.1) Android application.

I've placed the compiled libs into the `android/app/src/main/jniLibs` folder under target specific sub-folders, and they're picked up correctly by the build system and I can load the library with `DynamicLibrary.open()`.

The library is written with Rust, but it makes use of a C++ library and I'm getting the error `dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__cxa_pure_virtual" referenced by...`

So my question is, how exactly do I tell the build system to link against the C++ runtime?

The [Android 'C++ library support' page](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#cs) explains that the default runtime for `ndk-build` is `none`, and that I should add `APP_STL := c++_shared` to my `Application.mk` file.

Up until this point I didn't have an `Application.mk` file, but I could see that adding one might make sense, so I added the `APP_STL` definition to `android/app/jni/Application.mk`, and after some reading I decided that I should also add an `Android.mk` file (I don't know if it's actually required), with the following contents:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfoo.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

From what I understand these then [need to be picked up by Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds), so in `android/app/build.gradle` I've added:

```
...

android {
    ...

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'jni/Android.mk'
            path 'jni/Application.mk'
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't have any effect (I get the same error, and inspecting the APK shows that `libc++_shared.so` hasn't been included). I'm at the point where I'm thinking there's surely a simpler way to tell the build system to link against `libc++_shared.so`?

If I'm going down the right path, any ideas for why isn't my `APP_STL` definition being applied?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should put libc++_shared.so into dir:android/app/src/main/jniLibs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).